# Modify Excel File and save as CSV using vba

Tags: vba, csv, excel

I am working on populating a new application full of resident data. I have to export a list of residents for each property. Unfortunatly the new application has to have the residents imported 1 property at a time. This means im stuck loading 200+ properties by exporting an excel file, slightly modifing the data and then importing into the new application.

For each property that is exported I must remove a '-' from the first column and i have to remove all of the ',' throughout the entire document. I then change the formating on a date column to 'mm/dd/yyyy'. Then the document is saved as a CSV and can be imported.

I would like to write a script that can perform the updates to the excel file and save it to a csv. Please advise if this is worth my time. This is a one time load so it might be better to just power through.

Thank You

Comment: do you know any scripting languages? It might be easier to convert it to csv first (just using save-as in Excel), then use something like Python, Ruby or another language to manipulate the data and change the files.

Comment: So, to clarify, you're performing the same action on 200 different worksheets? Are you currently using replace all in the find & replace dialog, or do you require more fine-grained control than that?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a little prematurely, as I'm not certain this is what you want to achieve,  but you could try this (save first):

```
Sub replaceStuff()

    ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Replace "-", ""
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Replace ",", ""
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "doc", xlCSVWindows

End Sub
```